# When and how to release resources in Dart?

Tags: dart, resources, destructor, raii

What is a good way to close/release resources, when we do not have destructors in Dart?

For example take a Database class:

```
class Database {

  final String filename;

  RandomAccessFile _file;  

  Database(this.filename) {
    _file = File(filename).openSync();
  }

  // more reading, writing methods...
}
```

We surely should call `_file.close()` somewhere, and we can add a method to the `Database` class to do so. This just seems to shift the problem to another class, not solve it.

I guess I am looking for some kind of c++ `RAII`-ish thingy here, but with no clean-up methods I can only think of trivial short-lived objects to support something similar.

Comment: Could you find the answer? How to release sources?

Comment: @ishak No, I guess it's manual resource management. Also see this related github issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/345